# Cauchy Schwarz inequality using L1 norm

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

1) Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that the absolute value of vector inner product is always less or equal to product of norms of individual vectors i.e.,
$|a^Tb|\leq\Vert a\Vert_2 \Vert b\Vert_2$.

Does this inequality hold true for any Lp vector norms especially the L1 norm i.e., $|a^Tb|\leq\Vert a\Vert_1 \Vert b\Vert_1$.? If yes any Proofs?

---

2) Does this Cauchy-Schwarz inequality hold for a matrix $A$ having linearly independent columns $|A^Tb|\leq\Vert A\Vert_F \Vert b\Vert_2$

Comment: It's true for any $p$-norm with $1\leq p \leq 2$ and false for $p>2$. To see this simply note that $\| \cdot \|_2\leq \| \cdot \|_p$ whenever the first condition is satisfied. On the other hand if $p>2$ then with $a=b=(1,\ldots,1)$ the LHS is $n$ (the dimension), while the RHS is $n^{2/p}$.

Comment: @Jose27 can you comment on the first answer, as i thought the same answer you suggested.

Comment: Here is the reason why: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds true for vectors in an inner product space; now inner product gives rise to a norm, but the converse is false.

Comment: @Chee Han So does that mean inequality using L1 holds true. And what about the second inequality i asked for.

Comment: The $L^1$ norm doesn't satisfy the parallelogram identity, so it is not induced by an inner product, hence the inequality fails. Note that this is a necessary and sufficient condition. Since all norms on finite dimensional space are equivalent, I suspect the second inequality is true. (possibly with a constant)

Comment: @Chee Han Thanks for update. Regarding second inequality, i found it true for some computer simulations but i wish it can proved in some simple way. Or i find some counter examples.

Comment: I think you can try to prove it by your definition of matrix norm, shouldn't be too hard IMHO. (some messy algebraic or probably start with 3x3 matrix first).

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't hold in $L^1$. Take $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=g(x)=0$ elsewhere.

$\Vert f \Vert_1=\Vert g \Vert_1=2$ but $\int fg =+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for help, but can you explain in terms of vectors with transpose involved. And what about second part.?

Comment: I think holder's inequality which is valid for all Lp norms, for p=q=2 is same as Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I think OP meant the setting to be $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. $\{ 1,\ldots, n\}$ with counting measure), not a general measure space.